# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to read and write images to the external storage in my app. From what I read the following is the correct way to get a handle on the directory.

```
 File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File picturesDir = new File(externalStorageDir, "Pictures");
```

However ...

```
 picturesDir.exists(); // == null
 picturesDir.mkdir(); // == false
```

Is this because I'm using the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make sure you have external storage enabled:

In Eclipse, go to Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager. Select the appropriate AVD and then click Edit. 
[image: Window - Android SDK and AVD Manager]

Make sure you have SD card support enabled. If you do not, click the "New" button and select the "SD Card Support" option.

[image: Edit screen]

EDIT: Also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to the manifest.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to the manifest. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yep - I added that to the solution for future reference

Answer (score 1):

By default, the emulator will be launched without a sd card.
You should create a sd card image first by using the `mksdcard` command in console.
See SDK document:https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard.html

Hence, in the console, type the command to launch an emulator with that sd card:

```
    emulator -avd <emulator name> -sdcard <sdcard image name>
```

For better performance, I strongly suggest you debug your app via a real device.