# My File[] Nullpointerexecption error

Tags: android

```
String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/books";
File file=new File(folder);

File[] f;
f=file.listFiles(); //////f==null; 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f[1].toString(),    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I am not able to fix the error . I need to help. Thanks.

Comment: It would help the community greatly if you include your Log output

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is you can have a check like below

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/books";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File f = new File(path);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
if(file!=null&&file.length>0){

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }else{

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "folder is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

what above code is doing basically it is checking that if length is greater the 0 and file objext is not null. that display the toast containing second file name in the list.

Comment: Note in this response File f is never a null object reference. With a primitive array, failure to initialize doesn't assign a size to the array. This causes many problems, including NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

'file' is of File not Folder . That is why you can not get anything on calling file.listFiles() .

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/books";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File f = new File(path);        

 if (f.isDirectory()){
File file[] = f.listFiles();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }else{

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "folder is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `directory path` does not exists.

Check the documentation of [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()). It says

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs**.

You are giving a incorrect directory path, that is why `file.listFiles();` is returning null.

As you are using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, may be you have not enabled external storage for emulator. Just make sure that you have enabled external storage, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591531/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-on-the-emulator) link will be helpful.

It's safer to check if `f` is null before accessing it:

```
   if(f!=null){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f[1].toString(),    
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // also size of f[], if you really want to access f[1]
   }
```

Comment: In fact books folder contains 10 mp3 file.But , emulator writes "folder is empty".

Comment: @kenanshukurov you have media files in the emulator directory? and you are using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, does that even apply for emulator?

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: what does your `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` return?

Comment: Environment.getExternalDtorageDirectory() return mounted

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.devoloper.player .Home.onCreate(Home.java:122)             LIne122 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: your `data/data/.........../books` has files but not `mnt/sdcard/books`, thats your problem.

Comment: Thanks fo help. I understand to you

Comment: @kenanshukurov I am glad that it helped :)

Comment: Right way was your answer